# Main difference between using define and let in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

What are the main reasons why someone would use `let`:

```
(let((x 4)) (+ x 12))
```

Instead of doing the same thing with a `define`:

```
(define x 4)
(+ x 12)
```

Would there be examples of things that would work with one that wouldn't work with the other approach?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I started by reading that, but not really. All it says is that `let` is more consistently defined in the standard. I'm more looking for practical examples.

Comment: Read the accepted answer in that question, then refine your own question, asking more specifically about the things you didn't understand in the accepted answer.  The answer *doesn't* just say that `let` is more consistently defined.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- OP should read _all_ of the answers on the dupe before formulating a more specific question; each of the answers there has something to add.